# YOLOV8 hardware requirements and also laptop shutting down

Tags: python, yolov8

I have a laptop with following configurations

```
 Processor : AMD Ryzen 7 4800H with Radeon Graphics            2.90 GHz
 Installed RAM : 16.0 GB (15.4 GB usable)
 Windows Edition : Windows 11 Home Single Language
 Version : 22H2
 OS : 22621.1555
 NVIDIA GTX GEFORCE 1650 GRAPHICS CARD
 NVIDIA DRIVER : 31.0.15.3161
```

Its a brand new laptop
With following Python and CUDA installed:

```
Python 3.10.11

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 531.61                 Driver Version: 531.61       CUDA Version: 12.1     |
|-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                      TCC/WDDM | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf            Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                      |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650       WDDM | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   44C    P0               15W /  N/A|      0MiB /  4096MiB |      0%      Default |
|                                         |                      |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                            |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                            GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                             Usage      |
|=======================================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                           |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

But whenever I try to run my YOLOV8 model for object detection on this, it shuts down during 1st epoch only. Not sure why its happening. Any help is highly appreciated.

My Python  code

```
import tensorflow as tf
from ultralytics import YOLO
print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')))
print(tf.test.is_built_with_cuda())
print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))

# Create a TensorFlow session with GPU growth enabled
config = tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
sess = tf.compat.v1.Session(config=config)
physical_devices = tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], True)
print(tf.test.is_built_with_cuda())
# Run your code in the session
with sess.as_default():
   # Load the model.
   model = YOLO('yolov8n.pt')
   
   # Training.
   results = model.train(
      data='data.yaml',
      imgsz=640,
      epochs=5,
      batch=8,
      name='yolov8n_custom')
```

PS I would also like to know what are the hardware requirements for YOLOV8

Comment: Each Stack Overflow question should have only one question; and hardware specifications are outside our scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned, your laptop's graphics card is GTX1650, which only has 4GB of graphics memory. You can try setting the batch in the code to 4, 2, or 1 because my graphics card is 3060 and it has 6GB of memory. When I set the batch to 8, I will also report an error

Comment: Thanks. Just did that and it worked. Also I used yolov8 small.